# Can I use LEFT OUTER JOIN, and NULL, instead of one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have those tables:
[image: Tables]

And the question is:
[image: Question]

The query that I wrote is

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.RID, R.Name
  FROM Restaurant R
  LEFT OUTER JOIN VISIT V
    ON V.RID = R.RID
  WHERE V.CID IS NULL
```

Do you think this is the right way to approach this query?
Can it cause any problems?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for that question. Also, don't post images of code but copy the text in a codeblock.

Comment: @Idan . . . Your method is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways this problem can be approached, but using a left join and looking for nulls is my preferred one. Other ways include using NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery

```
SELECT id FROM r WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM v WHERE v.rid = r.id
)
```

and using MINUS to take the entire list of restaurant ID minus the list of restaurant ID that are in the visit table

```
SELECT id FROM r
MINUS
SELECT rid FROM v
```

In this form, of course, you'd have to do a join if you wanted any more data from the restaurants table

This isn't an exhaustive list. Your left join approach is fine and "won't cause any problems" (whatever you think they might be?)

You don't need to use distinct; by nature of the left join the rows that have zero visits on the right hand side will all be unique